# use mediator cqrs in TDD for integration test .net core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, xunit, mediator

i use Mediator in my project .

**[Demo Project on Github](https://github.com/kia9372/Date-Project)**

i want to use TDD in my project and integration test with .Net core 3.0

i write this code int test class for use intergration test with mediator :

```
public class SubscribeTest : IClassFixture<TravelRequest<Startup>>, IClassFixture<DbContextFactory>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly TravelRequest<Startup> request;
    private readonly DbContextFactory contextFactory;
    public SubscribeTest(TravelRequest<Startup> request , DbContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        this.request = request;
        this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        request.Dispose();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ListSubscribeAsync()
    {
        var add = await request.Get("/Subscribe/GetListSubscribe");
        await add.BodyAs<SubscribListDto>();
    }
}
```

and this is `TravelRequest` :

```
    public class TravelRequest<TStartup> : IDisposable where TStartup : class
    {
        private readonly HttpClient client;
        private readonly TestServer server;

        public TravelRequest()
        {
            var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<TStartup>().UseConfiguration(ConfigorationSingltonConfigoration.GetConfiguration());
            this.server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
            this.client = server.CreateClient();
        }
    }
```

and this is `ConfigorationSingltonConfigoration` for use the `appSetting-test.json` :

```
public class ConfigorationSingltonConfigoration
{
    private static IConfigurationRoot configuration;
    private ConfigorationSingltonConfigoration() { }
    public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        if (configuration is null)
            configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath("../../../")))
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings-test.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

and finally this is for set `DbContext` :

```
 public class DbContextFactory : IDisposable
{
    public TravelContext Context { get; private set; }
    public DbContextFactory()
    {
        var dbBuilder = GetContextBuilderOptions<TravelContext>("SqlServer");

        Context = new TravelContext(dbBuilder.Options);
        Context.Database.Migrate();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }

    public TravelContext GetRefreshContext()
    {
        var dbBuilder = GetContextBuilderOptions<TravelContext>("SqlServer");
        Context = new TravelContext(dbBuilder.Options);

        return Context;
    }

    private DbContextOptionsBuilder<TravelContext> GetContextBuilderOptions<T>(string connectionStringName)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigorationSingltonConfigoration.GetConfiguration().GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
        var contextBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TravelContext>();
        var servicesCollection = new ServiceCollection().AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().BuildServiceProvider();

        contextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString).UseInternalServiceProvider(servicesCollection);

        return contextBuilder;
    }
}
```

**Now** my problem is here , when i `RunTest` in result it show me this error :

> ---- System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList1[FluentValidation.IValidator1[Travel.Services.SubscribeServices.Query.SubscribeList.SubscribeListCommand]]' while attempting to activate 'Travel.Common.ValidateBehavior.ValidateCommandBehavior2[Travel.Services.SubscribeServices.Query.SubscribeList.SubscribeListCommand,Travel.Common.Operation.OperationResult1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Travel.ViewModel.SubscibeDto.SubscribListDto]]]'. ---- System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not implemented.

**whats the problem ? how can i solve ths problem ??? i put the source code of project in top of question**

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the validators are not registered into the container.

You can use the FluentValidation in .NET Core with Dependency Injection, by installing the nuget and than passing the assembly.

More references at [Using FluentValidation in .NET Core with Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202570/using-fluentvalidation-in-net-core-with-dependency-injection).

More reference of how you can do this at [Fluent Validation on .NET Core 2.0 does not register](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/551).